# Как отключить логирование базы EF Core (.net core)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef

Для работы с базой я использую ORM Entity Framework Core. После запуска приложения все запросы в базу у меня логируются в консоли. Логирование я не устанавливал. Как его отключить?

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer(opt =>
{
    opt.StopTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperConf));

builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
{
    builder
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:80")
    .AllowCredentials()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod();
}));

// DB Services
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AMContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AMIdentityContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opt =>
{
    opt.LoginPath = "/auth/login";
    opt.LogoutPath = "/auth/logut";
    opt.AccessDeniedPath = "/";
    opt.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(180);
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<DBUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
{
    config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    config.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
    config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    config.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AMIdentityContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot";
});
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new[] { new HangfireAuthFilter() }
});

app.MapControllers();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
    }
});


RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<HangFireTaskManager>("TaskParser", (method) => method.TaskParser(), "*/1 * * * * *");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<HangFireTaskManager>("PostParser", (method) => method.PostParser(), "*/1 * * * * *");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<HangFireTaskManager>("MonitorStatus", (method) => method.MonitorStatus(), "*/1 * * * * *");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<HangFireTaskManager>("CommentParser", (method) => method.CommentParser(), "*/1 * * * * *");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<HangFireTaskManager>("LikesParser", (method) => method.LikesParser(), "*/1 * * * * *");


// Init Roles
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    try
    {
        var rolesManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        await RoleInitializer.InitializeAsync(rolesManager);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
    }
}

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
builder.Host.ConfigureLogging(opt =>
{
    opt.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogLevel.Warning);
    opt.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", LogLevel.Warning);
});
```